# ionic start myapp --v2 is not working

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ubuntu 14.04. Installed ionic and cordova. used command `ionic start myapp --v2`
error thrown is

```
[ERROR] Sorry! The --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed.
        Use the --type option. (ionic start --help)

        For Ionic Angular projects, try ionic start ionreddit --type=ionic-angular
```

Used `ionic start myapp blank --type=ionic2`
Error

```
Unable to find starter type for ionic2
```

Comment: `ionic start myapp blank`  will create the ionic 3 in order to create your ionic 2 project update your package.json file to the version you need and `npm install` it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command for Ionic cli v3.x is:

```
ionic start myapp blank --type ionic-angular
```

If you want ionic 1

```
ionic start myapp blank --type ionic1
```

Check the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/).

You wont get a strictly ionic v2 project.

Comment: What is not clear to me is how to begin a ionic2 project. I am pretty new at this so help is appreciated.

Comment: [ionic 3](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-3-0-has-arrived/) is just an update from v2. It uses angular 4 and introduces lazy loading..Otherwise it is pretty much the same. All the version 2 syntax works for v3

Comment: I know angular 2 only. So if i create a ionic 3 project, can i use angular 2 in it?

Answer (score 2):

actually if u already install the ionic, the default is ionic v2, so that's mean u only need type
`ionic start myApp blank`
 but if u wanted to install ionic v1, u must adding `--type ionic1` like this `ionic start myApp blank --type ionic1`